# Can we do WRITE operation in GIT like COMMIT, MERGE etc using PHP?

Tags: php, git

Can we do WRITE operation in GIT like **commit** **merge** etc using PHP? I have seen code for reading commit messages using PHP but can we do write operation?
Any help on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284283/is-there-a-good-php-git-client-with-http-support

Comment: How is this question a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801983/how-to-create-a-commit-and-push-into-repo-with-github-api-v3?! The OP is not asking about GitHub API...

Comment: Thank you for the comments,I asked specifically for PHP.